# the automorphism group  of  the general linear group GL(n,F) 

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filed, $\mathcal{G}=GL(n,\mathcal{F})$, all n×n invertible matrices
on  $\mathcal{F}$, What is $Aut(\mathcal{G})$ ?

Comment: This is probably too standard a textbook question to be asked on MO.  Have you tried more elementary searches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Chapt.IV in the book

Dieudonné, J. A.
La géométrie des groupes classiques. Springer-Verlag (1971).